# Does apex support dynamic System.Type methods for dynamic deserialization?

Tags: apex, dynamic

Right now I am doing a deserialize/serialize trick to remove a field on the account record. I want to be able to abstract this code from just the account object to sObjects in general. Right now I am doing this in the following way:

```
masterRecord = (Account) JSON.deserialize( JSON.serialize( sobjMap1 ), Account.class );
```

I would rather the following code to make this dynamic:

```
String DynamicSobject = 'Account';

Map<String, Object> sobjMap1 = new Map<String, Object>( masterRecord.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() );

sobjMap1.remove( 'CreatedDate' );

masterRecord = (Sobject) JSON.deserialize( JSON.serialize( sobjMap1 ), DynamicSobject.class );
```

Is the .class method able to be dynamic?

maybe something like the following would work?

```
(DynamicSobject).getSObjectType().getDescribe().Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Type.forName for this purpose. The only change you really need to make is...

```
masterRecord = (Sobject) JSON.deserialize(
  JSON.serialize( sobjMap1 ), 
  Type.forName('Schema.'+DynamicSobject) );
```

Just, obviously, don't create a class named Schema in your database, unless you want this to break.

You can also use Type directly if you had an otherwise static reference to it.

```
public static sObject stripFields(sObject record, Set<String> fields, Type sObjectClass) { 
// ...
masterRecord = (Sobject) JSON.deserialize(
  JSON.serialize( sobjMap1 ), 
  sObjectClass );
```

I'd probably use this to avoid accidental breakages in the future (e.g. someone creating a Schema class).

Comment: Is there a reason you add the "Schema." on the type name? I've noticed you do this in other answers to other questions but we don't do this in our code. We just do Type.forName(theName), where theName is the fully qualified name for the object we want to access like "namespace__TheObjectType__c", for example.

Comment: @PhilW I recommend this approach to the general public because developers tend to accidentally create classes named Account or Contact, thus unwittingly causing code like this to fail in special circumstances. I've also observed that developers are reticent to create a class named Schema, which tends to immediately invalidate an entire org's code (right along with a class named Test), so this advice works for most developers. You don't need to use Schema as long as you remember not to accidentally shadow the main sObject variables.